# Reference request for parabolic equations in weak formulation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I want to learn about parabolic equations, and its regularity theory. I'm interested in non-homogenous boundary value problems, with Neumann, and Dirichlet conditions, and mixes of them (on different disconnected parts of the domain).

Do you have a good, *user friendly* textbook or reference where all of this is treated from the ground up?

This reference should also present the different weak formulations (some are with fractional Sobolev spaces, some are not...) and put them in relation.